# Find a closed form expression for $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} i^2\cdot x^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I think I'm supposed to use calculus somewhere but I'm completely lost.

Comment: I don't know how to do the latex.

Comment: I just fixed it sorry.

Comment: I think it was  $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(i^2)x^i$$. Correct?

Comment: Do you want this?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Start with $1/(1-x)=\sum x^n$ and differentiate termwise

Comment: @dirtysocks45 this sequence is divergent

Comment: Joe, I started with that but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Also I should have stated that |x| < 1

Comment: @dirtysocks45 well you should mention in the question what you tried and what you got

Answer (score 2):

First, show that for $|x|<1$, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$. You can get this from differentiating $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$ and multiplying by $x$ (to take $x^{n-1}$ back to $x^n$ after differentiating).

Then, just repeat, i.e. differentiate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ and multiply by $x$ to find $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $i^2=(i+2)(i+1)-3(i+1)+1$. Then:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^\infty i^2 x^i &= \sum (i+2)(i+1)x^i -3\sum (i+1)x^i + \sum x^i\\
&=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)-3\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) + \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

(Just playing around here)

Since
$n^2
=\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2x^n
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n x^n (2i-1)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=i}^{\infty} x^n (2i-1)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(2i-1)\sum_{n=i}^{\infty} x^n \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(2i-1)\frac{x^i}{1-x} \\
&=\frac1{1-x}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(2i-1)x^i \\
&=\frac1{1-x}\left(2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}ix^i-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^i\right) \\
\end{array}
$

Doing the same,
but with
$n
=\sum_{i=1}^n 1
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^n
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n\sum_{i=1}^n 1\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n x^n \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=i}^{\infty} x^n \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=i}^{\infty} x^n \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{1-x} \\
&=\frac1{1-x}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^i \\
&=\frac1{1-x}\frac{x}{1-x} \\
&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
(what do you know -
looks like it's going to work!)

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2x^n
&=\frac1{1-x}\left(2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}ix^i-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^i\right) \\
&=\frac1{1-x}\left(2\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} -\frac{x}{1-x}\right) \\
&=\frac1{(1-x)^3}\left(2x -x(1-x)\right) \\
&=\frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)^3} \\
\text{or}&=\frac{2x}{(1-x)^3}-\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Marty did the hard part. ... = ${x(x+1)\over (1-x)^3}$.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, I was just playing around based on noticing that $\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1) = n^2$. I actually found my answer amusing. I could be generalized to higher powers, but, at the moment, I don't think I'll bother.